# Checking if Receipt is Released

Tags: acumatica

I want to execute code when a receipt is released. The code I have did work, but is no longer working only a few days later.  Nothing was done to cause this to suddenly stop working. The code I have is as follows:

```
public class INReceiptEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<INReceiptEntry>
{  
  ... 
  protected void INRegister_RowPersisted(PXCache cache, PXRowPersistedEventArgs e)
    {
        INRegister reg = (INRegister)e.Row;           
        if (reg != null)
        {
            if (e.TranStatus == PXTranStatus.Completed)
            {
                if (reg.Released == true)
                {
                    //Code
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there anything I am missing or any reason this code worked one day but is no longer working the next?

Comment: which graph does your included code live in? INDocumentRelease, INReleaseProcess, or INReceiptEntry? It is possible that the set of released occurs in one of the processing graphs and not the data entry graph. Including which graph will help in finding a resolution.

Comment: public class INReceiptEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<INReceiptEntry> Is that what you were asking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that you need to move your code to INDocumentRelease as this is the graph that processes ALL inventory transactions and sets the released field to true once complete.

Add your code to a INReleasePRocess graph extension in a INRegister RowUpdated or Released Field Updated and this way too your code should be wrapped within the transaction that processes the batch. Dont forget to check for receipts only as this graph processes all inventory transactions.

If you look at the source you can see at the end of INReleasePRocess.ReleaseDocProc the Released field is set, doc is updated, and the transaction is then complete.

Comment: I don't understand how my code above worked before and doesn't now. I programmed it to make sure the transaction was complete which should then grab the updated database entry for that view which would should be set to .Released = true. Any clue why it did work for a few days, but isn't anymore? Again, nothing was changed with the screen or the code.

Comment: if you are refreshing the data after the release finishes in the release page it is possible you could get the correct value... but i dont see how persisted was working before

Comment: Alright, maybe it was a fluke. I know I've had that happen in the past a few times as well. Your solution makes sense to me. I'm going to try to implement it.

Comment: i agree, while it might have been working before, the code would serve a better home in INReleaseProcess. Hope it works out.